# How print array of object in ng-repeat with out using key.value in angular.js dynamically?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular.js for font-end and node.js for server side.

Now, I am having some list of values in array randomly.

Html code :

```
<html ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainController'>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="jumbotron">
      <table><tr ng-repeat="report in reports">
        <td style="padding-left:10px;">{{report.salary_head_value11}}</td>
        <td style="padding-left:10px;">{{report.salary_head_value12}}</td>
        <td style="padding-left:10px;">{{report.salary_head_value13}}</td>
        <td style="padding-left:10px;">{{report.salary_head_value14}}</td>
        <td style="padding-left:10px;">{{report.salary_head_value15}}</td>

        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <pre>{{ cleanData | json}}</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

Controller code :

```
angular.module('app', [])

.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {
$scope.reports = [{
"salary_head_value11":100,
"salary_head_value12":300,
"salary_head_value13":200,
"salary_head_value14":800,
"salary_head_value15":500
},{
"salary_head_value11":200,
"salary_head_value12":400,
"salary_head_value13":900,
"salary_head_value14":800,
"salary_head_value15":600
}];

}]);
```

Output :

[image]

Expected code :

i want to print the same output without using `{{report.salary_head_value11}} ......{{report.salary_head_value15}}` in ng-repeat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont need the string name `salary_head_value`, you can turn the array of objects into a 2d array:

```
$scope.reports = [
    [ 100, 300, 200, 800, 500 ],
    [ 200, 400, 900, 800, 600 ]
];
```

Then in HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="report in reports">
        <td style="padding-left:10px;" ng-repeat="val in report">{{val}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Note: untested, this is the concept, please modify it if there are syntax errors

Comment: ,i have one more doubt in the above query, How to skip first 2 value in ng repeat in <td> values.

Comment: you want to skip first 2? `ng-show="$index > 1"` maybe.

Comment: great it's also working fine ,one more thing, how skip last index value.

Comment: the output not printed as sequence, how to print as sequence.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? What do you mean by sequence